# "Now" before and after the verb. Do they both have the same meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Placing the adverb "now" before or after the verb brings some type of change to the meaning of the sentence, as in the example below:

Thank you for inviting me to your party and sharing this wonderful news with me. **I now need to go** to my sister's house and tell her all about you and Paul finally deciding to get married. You know how much she always hoped for the two of you to be together.

Thank you for inviting me to your party and sharing this wonderful news with me. **Now I need to go** to my sister's house and tell her all about you and Paul finally deciding to get married. You know how much she always hoped for the two of you to be together.

Comment: Also [*We need now to go*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22we+need+now+to+go%22) and [*We need to now go*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22we+need+to+now+go%22) and [*We need to go now*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22we+need+to+go+now%22) For all practical purposes I'd say they all mean the same thing. I can't see how a theoretical distinction between adverbial ***now*** modifying ***need*** or ***go*** could mean different things in the real world.

Comment: The title of your post **asks whether there is** a difference in meaning, while the body of your post **asserts** that there **is** one. Leaving that inconsistency aside, what evidence suggests to you that there is a difference, and what do you understand, believe, or suspect about the nature of that difference?

Comment: I’d encourage you to edit your post to address these matters. As it currently stands, I’m voting to close it as lacking in detail.

Comment: Sorry, Paul, but I really don't understand. As far as I can say the title of my post asks if using the adverb "now" before and after the verb brings some difference in the meaning of the sentence and in the body I provide two similar sentences, each one using one of the options.  I don't see where I'm asserting that there is a difference. I would happily make whatever changes were necessary, but I honestly don't know what to change.

Comment: The only reason I supposed that could be some difference is that it crossed my mind that maybe using the "now I need to go" option could mean "now that you shared those news with me", or "because I am now aware of those news" I must go and tell about them to my sister, and using the "I now need to go" it could be more related to a timing issue, maybe it was getting late, maybe her sister wasn't home much longer or something like that. I have nothing to suggest that there is a difference, just reading and re-reading that sentence several times it seemed to me that such a difference could exist.